# why is the effect of an object falling from high altitude much bigger than an object falling from 0/low altitude

Tags: forces, free-fall

the force of an object is
F = m . a
where m is the mass, and a is the acceleration.

if an object falls from say 100 m on a flat glass, it will shatter it to pieces.
but if you just carefully put the same object on the same flat glass, nothing would happen,  although the force is the same in both cases (the mass is the same and the acceleration is always 9.8 m/s^2)
so there must be another factor that controls the effects of objects on other objects, what is it?

Comment: It's the kinetic energy: $E=1/2 mv^2$. When the object falls from higher altitude it has a greater velocity when it reaches the glass, thus a greater kinetic energy which is used to break the glass

Comment: so $E = 1/2 F. v$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> although the force is the same in both cases

No, the force is not the same! In the case where you gently place the object with almost zero speed on the glass, the force exerted by the glass is indeed close to $mg$. For the object falling 100 m, at a speed of about 44 m/s (97 mph), the force must be much greater. There are actually 2 ways to look at it.

1. The average force will be $F_{ave}=\frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}=\frac{mv}{\Delta t}$, where $\Delta t$ is the small time interval during which the glass interacts with the object and causes it to stop. Consider the mass to be about 50 g, and the stopping time to be about 1 millisecond (just a guess, but pretty reasonable). Then the *average* force would be 2200 N, about $4500\times$ the weight.
2. One could also consider the work done by the glass, which would be $$W=F_{ave}\Delta x$$ where $\Delta x$ would be the flexing distance of the glass as it stops the falling object. Assume the glass flexes about 10 mm. The work must be equal in magnitude to the kinetic energy:
   $$F_{ave}(0.010)=0.5 (0.050)(44)^2$$ giving an average force of about 4800 N. Obviously, these are estimates for the order of magnitude, but the bottom line is, the glass must exert a force much larger than the object's mass to stop the object.

Another critical aspect is the area of interaction. A given force over a large area might not exceed the structural strength of the glass, whereas the same force in a very small area could easily break the glass. Consider the difference in trying to poke a hole in a piece of cardboard versus using a sharp knife. The area of the knife blade interaction is much smaller and will easily "break" the cardboard surface.

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration due to gravity is only responsible for a portion of the force that the glass experiences.

If you drop an object from 100m high, it will land on the glass with considerable speed. If the glass is going to avoid breaking, it must absorb the object's velocity before it breaks from bending.

$$\Delta v^2 = 2a \Delta x$$
$$a = \frac{\Delta v^2}{2\Delta x}$$

So the force the glass must exert on the object in order to avoid breaking is both the object's weight and the force required to decelerate it:

$$F = mg + \frac{m\Delta v^2}{2\Delta x}$$

$v$, of course, increases with the height from which the object was dropped. In fact, if the object is initially at rest (when dropped), $\Delta v^2$ will be equal to $gh$:

$$F = mg + \frac{mgh}{2\Delta x}$$